# Angular 2, mapping the values of object item into class using Cerialize Library

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I've got a JSON data which goes like this :

```
{
"courses_purchased_count": 0,
"featured_lesson": {
    "lesson": {
        "id": 290,
        "name": "Christmas Test  #290",
        "course": {
            "id": 43,
            "name": "Christmas Test ",
            "description": "",
            "teacher": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Sandy's Teacher",
                "email": "xyz@s.com",
                "role": "TEACHER",
                "token": "xyz",
                "about": "Blah blah blah ",
                "phone": "2222222222",
                "image_url": "xyz",
                "payment_information": {}
            },
            "image": "xyz",
            "cover_image": "xyz",
            "course_type": "WEEKLY_ONGOING",
    },
    "status": "NEXT_AVAILABLE"
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to map the data into a class which I have created in my models.ts which goes like this using [Cerializable Library](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize#deserializing_new_instances)

**models.ts**

```
import { deserialize, deserializeAs, Deserialize } from 'cerialize';

/* UTILTY METHODS */

export function cast(data, modelClass) {
  return Deserialize(data, modelClass)
}

export function castCollection (collection, modelClass) {
  return collection.map( item => cast(item, modelClass))
}

/* MODELS */

export class Teacher {

  @deserialize name: string
}

export class Course {

  @deserialize id: number
  @deserialize name: string
  @deserialize image: string
  @deserializeAs(Teacher) teacher : Teacher

}

export class Lesson {

  @deserialize id: number
  @deserialize name: string
  @deserialize start_time : Date
  @deserializeAs(Course) course : Course
}

export class Featured {
  @deserialize status : string
  @deserializeAs(Lesson) lesson : Lesson
}
```

In my homepage I just want to show up the data from the lesson object like this : **{{featured_lesson.lesson.name}}** or from course object like **{{featured.lesson.course.name}}** but due to some sort of error I'm getting this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

The homepage components are :

**homepage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { deserialize, Deserialize } from 'cerialize'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { cast, castCollection, Lesson, Featured } from "../../../models/models";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-classes',
  templateUrl: './my-classes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-classes.component.css']
})

export class MyClassesComponent implements OnInit {

   featured_lesson : Featured[] = []

   constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

   ngOnInit() {

   }

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.http.get("/ui/student/home").subscribe( data => {
       this.featured_lesson = castCollection(data['featured_lesson'], Featured)
   })
   }
 }
```

**homepage.component.html**

```
<layout-app>

  <div>
    {{featured_lesson.lesson.name}}
  </div>

</layout-app>
```

Since I've tried doing these things, these are :

- feautred_lesson : Featured[] = {}, since I thot it is an object so may be giving the object will do but we got an error saying `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Featured[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.`
- I tried getting value of the "status" like this **{{featured_lesson.status}}** which gave the error as `ERROR TypeError: collection.map is not a function
  at castCollection (models.ts:10)`
- Treid doing this for getting the object like this :

  `ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.http.get("/ui/student/home").subscribe( data => {
    this.lessons = castCollection(data['other_lessons'], Lesson)
    //this.featured_lesson = castCollection(data['featured_lesson'], Featured)
    this.featured_lesson = data['featured_lesson']
  })`

and in console.log(this.featured_lesson) gave me the result but when I tried to print it in my html file like this **{{featured_lesson.lesson.name}}** same error `cannot read porperty "name"`

I'm searching for the solution, guidance is required since I'm a leaner and want to know about angular more. This things will help me for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your component, `featured_lesson` is a table :

```
featured_lesson : Featured[] = []
```

But in your HTML, you expect it to be an object :

```
<div>
  {{featured_lesson.lesson.name}}
</div>
```

A table isn't an object (well ... Not as you expect it to be here at least), meaning you don't have access to your object properties inside your array.

If you want to have access to it, you have two solutions :

1 - Transform your `featured_lesson` into an object :

```
featured_lesson : Featured = new Featured();
```

2 - Show an object in your HTML :

```
{{featured_lesson[0].lesson.name}}
```

Comment: I have tried the same solution which you gave me now I'm getting an error like this  : `HomePage.component.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'lesson' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]`

Comment: Well which one did you chose ?

Comment: The first one. In my html I defined it like this `{{featured_lesson.lesson.id}}` and I got `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]`

Comment: Because you also have to give it a value. Sorry, it was implicit. In your component, you're getting an array of values by your service, right ? Well, you should take one item of this array (try with the first one), and apply it to your variable.

Comment: Can you please give me demo since I have tried going with the first option and in my html I have defined it as above and I'm getting an error